# ldap запрос. Список всех пользователей в моей OU

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

Не получается составить ldap запрос для python скрипта.
Как получить список всех пользователей входящих в определенную OU?
Пробовал вот так

```
'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(OU=my_OU,OU=Filial,DC=my,DC=domen,DC=ru))'
```

и так (предварительно задав cn в атрибутах OU)

```
'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=my_OU,OU=Filial,DC=my,DC=domen,DC=ru))'
```

Запрос возвращает пустой список

Answer (score 0):

Строка запроса в Python имеет вид `conn.search(AD_SEARCH_TREE, '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))', ldap3.SUBTREE, attributes=['cn'])`
Так вот AD_SEARCH_TREE должно иметь значение указывающее на конкретное OU.
Может конечно это и решается самим ldap-запросом, но я так и не нашел как.

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , наверно все таки ответ. До другого я не дошел, и других предложений не услышал.